# How to use Boolean variable in TK, python?

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

there are four radiobuttons, and let's called them a, b, c, d.
my task is that make Text widget to show 'correct', when b, d are checked.

so I think I should use boolean variable, but I don't know how to start..

Comment: Radio buttons and *b, d are checked.*? Do you mean Check buttons or when the radio button is selected, then insert ```correct``` in the ```Text``` widget?

Comment: Only one radiobutton must be selectable..

Answer (score 1):

`BooleanVar()` can be imported from `tkinter`.

`.get()` can be used to get the value.

`.set()` can be used to set the value. Expecting `True` or `False`.

```py
>>> import tkinter as tk
>>> root = tk.Tk()  # Make sure to execute this first before using BooleanVar().
>>> boolvar = tk.BooleanVar()
>>> boolvar
<tkinter.BooleanVar object at 0x000002053CC9E940>
>>> boolvar.set(True)
>>> boolvar.get()
True
>>> boolvar.set(False)
>>> boolvar.get()
False
>>>
```

By default the boolean variable returns `False`.

```py
>>> a = tk.BooleanVar()
>>> a.get()
False
```

Side note: It is good practice to import like `import tkinter as tk` instead of `from tkinter import *` because using namespace like `tk` instead of directly calling the function makes it much easier to identify where the objects belong to.

Answer (score 0):

```
from Tkinter import *

v = BooleanVar()
```

I think above code might be helpful for you.

Comment: Are you using python 2.x

Comment: Thank u! may I ask what is difference between BooleanVar, StringVar, and IntVar?

Comment: IntVar() # Holds an integer; default value 0
DoubleVar() # Holds a float; default value 0.0
BooleanVar() # Holds a boolean, returns 0 for False and 1 for True

Comment: My Pleasure :), I am also working on a python project, it would be great if you can connect to me directly.